# Visual Studio F# error - FSharp.Core.sigdata

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#

I've installed the latest FSharp bundle, but now whenever I hit control-spacebar in Visual Studio, I get this error:

> Problem reading assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a': Error opening
> binary file
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll':
> FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core

**Edit 1**

Also, when I try to compile, I get the following errors:

> FSC: error FS1223: FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core
>
> FSC: error FS0229: Error opening binary file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll': FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core
>
> FSC: error FS3160: Problem reading assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a': Error opening binary file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll': FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core
>
> Done building project "Library1.fsproj" -- FAILED.

**Edit 2**

On top of that, I get the following errors when I try to run fsi.exe:

```
> Session termination detected. Press Enter to restart.



unknown(1,1): error FS1223: FSharp.Core.sigdata not found alongside FSharp.Core


unknown(1,1): error FS0229: Error opening binary file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll': Exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger+StopProcessing' was thrown.


unknown(1,1): error FS3160: Problem reading assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a': Exception of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger+StopProcessing' was thrown.
```

**Note: I can still run fsi.exe for F# 3.0. I'm only having this issue with 3.1 (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0)**

Any idea how I can get back to functioning F#?

**Edit 3**

It appears that I am again able to compile my F# projects after numerous repair installs/system reboots of things. The issues with fsi.exe and Visual Studio Intellisense remain.

Comment: Can you report this at https://github.com/MIcrosoft/visualfsharp  ?

Comment: Done. Also I noticed that I can't actually compile.